# React-file-viewer : Build error

Tags: reactjs

I want to use react-file-viewer, but i have an error when I build my project :

[image]

This is my code :

```
export default class ViewerYes extends React.Component<Props, State>{
    const file = './yes.png'
    const type = 'png'  
    public render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <FileViewer
                        fileType={type}
                        filePath={file}
                        errorComponent={CustomErrorComponent}
                        />
                </div>
            )
       }
    }
```

And I call the component in a parent component like this :

```
<ViewerYes/>
```

Do you have a solution about this issue ?
Thank you

Comment: What line is the #74? As there is the unexpected token ....

Comment: I posted a capture below :)

Comment: @AnaïsSaez did you find solution tho this issue. I am facing same issue